# What is practical use of '-x' parameter?

Tags: python, command-line

I am curios where in real-world applications people use following parameter?

> -x Excludes (skips) the first line of the main script’s source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're looking at, but both the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-x) and `python --help` have more information:

> Skip the first line of the source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of `#!cmd`. **This is intended for a DOS specific hack only.**

It was put in for some DOS-specific use case. People might find other, equally hacky use cases for it, but you can pretty much ignore its existence.

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question.